# My status with patent No. US5803294

Tags: ownership

would you be so kind to inform me of my status and my rights due to the fact that I share the right for the patent with the man that I never heard of.
Best regards,
Zvonimir Bello

Answer (score 0):

According to google's patent lookup, the payment status is lapsed.
http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US5803294

The other man listed is Sinisia Klein, meaning that both you and him have rights to the invention and can both give permission to use it.

Comment: It was expired at the time if the question - no one was needed to give permission.